# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch error on using "RedirectAttributes" in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting below error whenever I am using RedirectAttributes in my controller method if I am adding any other thing like ModelMap or Model then it is not giving any error. Why?

I checked on the net for the solution but I did not find anything.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

spring-servlet.xml

```
             <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
                xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">  


                <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
                <mvc:annotation-driven />
                <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
                    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
                    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
                </bean>

              <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
                  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
                  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
                  <property name="username" value="system" />
                  <property name="password" value="system" />
             </bean>
           <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
              <property name="configLocation">
                 <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
              </property>
              <property name="configurationClass">
                 <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
              </property>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                 <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 </props>
              </property>
           </bean>
           <bean id="userDAO" class="userDAO.UserDAOImpl"/>
            <bean id="userService" class="userService.UserServiceImpl"/>
                <bean id="viewResolver"  
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">  
                    <property name="viewClass">  
                        <value>  
                            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView  
                        </value>  
                    </property>  
                </bean>  
                <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">  
                    <property name="definitions">  
                        <list>  
                            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>  
                        </list>  
                    </property>  
                </bean>


                <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
                <bean id="transactionManager"
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
            </bean>

            </beans> 

        //Controller class
               @RequestMapping("/Check")
            public String Check(@ModelAttribute("adduser") User user,ModelMap model,RedirectAttributes rd)
    //This is my function 
            {
                System.out.println(user.getUsername());
                System.out.println(user.getPassword());
                rd.addFlashAttribute("ajay", "Cjal");
                model.addAttribute("Username",user.getUsername());
                User result=userService.getByUserName(user.getUsername());
                System.out.println(result);
                if(result == null)
                {
                    userService.addUser(user);
                    return "redirect:SuccessfulRegistration.html";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "redirect:RegistrationError.html";
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the Spring version you are using? RedirectAttributes has been added since Spring 3.1 release. Please check example at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/